# Avoid creating a new window

Tags: emacs

Since an emacs upgrade I made a long time ago (or was it when I changed my laptop, or when I changed my Ubuntu release? I can't remember), emacs keeps opening new windows whenever I click into a file link in grep-mode (for example). Before, I had this behavior:

- I have a window open (window 0)
- I run a grep command
- I get a new window, with the grep result (window 1)
- I select any line in the grep result, and a new buffer is opened in window 0

Which is what I want: maximum two windows opened, and I get to see around 30 lines per window. Now, instead, I get:

- I have a window open (window 0)
- I run a grep command
- I get a new window, with the grep result (window 1)
- I select any line in the grep result, a new buffer is opened in a *new window* (window 3). The windows have 30, 15, and 15 lines.

So now I have 3 windows instead of 2, with too few lines. This happens again, until a maximum of 4 open windows. To keep my windows at a minimum height, I need to keep on manually closing windows, which is very annoying.

I guess this has to do with the minimum height of the window, and how many lines the frame has, but I am unable to find the exact settings.

How can I tell emacs to open at most 2 windows in the active frame?

Comment: You may try http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Atomization, anyone? There are 13000 emacs questions in stackoverflow. I guess it is relevant enough here.

Comment: I didnt flag it as off topic, I was just suggesting you may have luck over there :)

Comment: Sure, sure, and your comment may actually have some merit, since this is not really a question about emacs programming ... But no idea how to migrate a question.

Comment: That's an option, but there is probaby an accepted way (tm) of doing that. Anyway, I'll do that, thx.